# Как в Oracle заменить в таблице 1999 год на 2001?

Tags: sql, oracle, дата, update

Есть таблица в Oracle под названием REM
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В столбце `P2` у меня хранятся даты. Дело в том, что мне нужно там, где у меня есть `1999` год заменить только год на `2001`. Как это сделать, помогите пожалуйста. Не понимаю этого.

```
UPDATE rem
SET p2 = TO_DATE('MM/DD/2001', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
WHERE p2 LIKE TO_DATE('MM/DD/1999', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
UPDATE rem
SET p2 = replace(to_char(p2, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), '1999', '2001')
WHERE trunc(p2, 'y') = to_date('01.01.1999', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, почему вы дополнительно используете условие WHERE, если функция REPLACE предполагает замену 1999 года на 2001 год?

Comment: @РэмКудусов с помощью `WHERE` мы выбираем строки, которые будем менять. `SET p2 = ...`  обновит все строки, которые будут выбраны. То есть запрос корректно отработает и без `WHERE`, но с ним будут обновлены только те записи, у которых год 1999